# Possible cheapest ways to travel from Munich to Konigssee and Salzburg

Tags: germany, munich, salzburg

I am planning to visit to Munich next month. According to my priority list, I want to visit Königssee and Salzburg.

Right now my plan is to pass a day for: *Munich - Königssee - Munich*
And another day: *Munich-Salzburg-Munich*.
But I am afraid, it may cost more (I do not have any idea yet though).

Will it be a good idea to follow this: *Munich - Königssee - Salzburg - Munich*? In that case, which place will be cheapest to pass the night, Salzburg or Near Königssee?

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What is `best` for you? Economical? Easier logistics? Voting to close as opinion-based.

Comment: For me, best means economical. I do not have problem to use public transport.

Comment: I suggest you try to be as specific as possible in the question body, then. ;)

Comment: I just edited and modified best to cheapest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Königssee and Salzburg are much closer to each other than to Munich, it should definitely save your some time and money, roughly 2 hours and 50 EUR. You'll have to decide whether that's worth the hassle of switching acommodations twice, dealing with luggage, etc.

You'll probably have more choice regarding acommodation in Salzburg.

Comment: Can you please tell me easiest station names?

Comment: @VessilliZaytsev Berchtesgaden is the tourist town at Königssee.